# Search for particular data in tickets and export that data to a server location

Tags: data, search, automation

I am wanting to search salesforce tickets for particular data like phone numbers in ticket notes. I want to export this list of phone number to a network location (a server). Ideally, the list of phone numbers will be formatted so that they follow a certain standard (numbers only and no spaces ex: 1234567890)

this only needs to be done once a day at 9pm and all tickets that the numbers were found on will be auto updated to close status.

currently, 6 people manually take these tickets and escalate them to one person. This person then manually extracts the phones and formats them after which they then upload the file to the network location. lastly, the ticket is then manually closed.

i want to automate this process which eliminates all this work described above.

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, I assume the Ticket notes is refering to the Case Description standard field. I would write a trigger on the Case object that after insert and/or update the trigger parses the Case Description field and creates a custom object record (you will need to create a custom object with a parent-child relationship field to the Case standard object). The trigger would populate the custom object relationship field with the Case's Salesforce ID and would populate a custom text field with the phone number string. The trigger would then update the status of the Case to closed.

You could then run Data Loader from the command line to extract the custom object records and drop the extract CSV in the desired shared drive. You could use task scheduler and some PowerShell scripts to make this run automatically and at the desired time. You may use formula fields on the custom object to add information about the parent case record as required for the extract.

Welcome to Salesforce Stackexchange!

Here I made a Visio with some more detail to help, this is just a high level overview of what you need to do based on my experience. Others may have better solutions.

[image]

Data Loader Command Line Documentation:

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_Data_Loader_from_the_command_line